# How do I differentiate between vim and vimdiff from within vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, vimdiff

I have a function in vim which will open all buffers as tabs. However after I add this function, vimdiff too opens the files to be compared as different tabs and hence doesn't show the differences. Is there a way where I can find out if its vim or vimdiff which is invoking my vimrc file?

```
function! OpenTabs()
    let bf=len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'))
    if bf > 1
      exe "tab 5sball"
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Related SO post about using tabs as buffers: [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103590/438329)

Comment: I found this question because I didn't want the workspace loaded by vim-workspace when VIm was executed by `git difftool` but in this case `let g:workspace_session_disable_on_args = 1` suits me better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`:help diff`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#diff) covers this:

> In your .vimrc file you could do something special when Vim was started in
>   diff mode.  You could use a construct like this:
>
> ```
>    if &diff
>       setup for diff mode
>    else
>       setup for non-diff mode
>    endif
> ```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `&diff` option like in your vimrc:

```
if &diff
    echo "in diff mode"
else
    echo "not in diff mode"
endif
```

See [`:h 'diff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27diff%27)

Comment: Snap! I'll upvote yours if you upvote mine ;)

Comment: Ahah I was 6 seconds too slow to click "submit"! Have my upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick respone! Wondering if there is an option to identify view & vi too?

Comment: @AnkitJain For the view you might check if all of your buffers have the `'readonly'` option set, or maybe you can alias `view` to set a vim variable that you would check on startup.

Comment: @AnkitJain `:h v:progname`

Comment: @ChristianBraband This is what I was looking for :)